# Schedule group disable write - with custom error

Tags: permissions

I'm looking for a good solution to what seems to be a simple problem.

I need to disable a user group from writing to any number of tables on a schedule - let say  Saturday between 0600 and 1200.  I'd like not to have to write special time handling for all the client applications.  It would be enough to display a custom error message from the database, something like "Write disable between 0600 and 1200", but this need to be generated at the DB side.

Is this at all possible ?

Comment: Depends on the database, and any implementation will likely be database-specific. Can't answer your question without understanding which database you're using.